# Why MySQL Workbench automatically sets NOT NULL for ID column that is PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My question is why MySQL Workbench automatically sets `NOT NULL` for ID column that is `PRIMARY KEY`? I thought that `PRIMARY KEY`'s can't be `NOT NULL` by definition? Is it really necessary to set it to `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Yes, a `PRIMARY KEY` column has to be `NOT NULL`. That happens in almost all (if not all) DBMS: MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, Postgres...

Comment: @ypercube - what do you mean by 'has to be' `NOT NULL` ? So if I would to create `PRIMARY KEY` column without defining `NOT NULL` it actually can store null value?

Comment: `NOT NULL` means that you cannot store `NULL` value. Only not null ones. It doesn't matter if you declare `NOT NULL` or not. If a column is part of the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, it is also `NOT NULL`.

Comment: @ypercube I know what `NOT NULL` means. You are writing that `PRIMARY KEY` is also `NOT NULL` by definition and I know that. That is why I am asking my question.

Comment: If you know that, why your question has: *"I thought that PRIMARY KEY's can't be NOT NULL by definition?"* Did you mean to write the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly setting the NOT NULL is simply an additional action to make this fact clear also for the non-experienced users. It doesn't hurt and you can safely ignore it.